# HardHat deploy script works on testnet but not on forked hardhat network

Tags: rpc, ethers.js, forks, buidler

The error that I am getting when running this is:

```
Error: Invalid RpcBlockWithTransactions or null
```

I have a contract called `PriceConsumerV3` and it makes a `view` function call on a contract. I am attempting to use [hardhats forking](https://hardhat.org/guides/mainnet-forking.html) functionality, but whenever I run this script from the forked version, (or even just the regular hardhat runtime environment) I get the error above.

However, when I use the `kovan` network as defined in my `hardhat.config.js` which uses an `RPC_URL` the script deploys and works fine.

```js
async function main() {
    const PriceConsumerV3 = await ethers.getContractFactory("PriceConsumerV3")
    const priceConsumerV3 = await PriceConsumerV3.deploy()
    await priceConsumerV3.deployed()
    console.log("priceConsumerV3 deployed to: ", priceConsumerV3.address)
    ethPrice = await priceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice()
    console.log("Price data for ETH: ", ethPrice.toString())
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out the issue was with `kovan`. You can currently only fork `mainnet`.

Comment: This will be fixed soon. You can join our discord server to get notified when that release is ready.